# Animation effect not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a simple jQuery slide show .the problem I am facing that when I use fade-out it works properly but when I am trying to use animate to slide all the images to the right it's not working ..
My jQuery code so far

HTML:

```
<div id ="slide">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">IMG1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">img2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

 $(document).ready(function (){    
      $('#slide').each(function (){    
          $(this).animate ({left:'700px'},4000)});
      });
 });
```

I am new to jQuery so please excuse me for this poor code .want to to know what am I doing wrong ! Thanks in advanced for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the HTML for your code?

Anyways, you cannot use multiple IDs on the same page.

Seems like you are using #slide on multiple elements. Instead use classname and then

```
$('.slide').each(function(){ 
   // your code here
});
```

While if there are some elements inside your div with id **#slide**, e.g you have **img** tags inside that **#slide** div,then use

```
 $('#slide img').each(function(){ 
   // your code here
});
```

Comment: I think I am not using multiple slide tag I will add my html

Comment: Well your html code isn't formatted correctly but i think the second loop in my answer should work fine for you. Just replace **.slide** with **#slide** in the second loop.

Comment: Tried that also not working ..and can you tell me how to format code on phone please I am pretty noob on stack overflow